# How to make a fragment?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-studio

I've never made a fragment before, and have been trying to get this to work. I followed some online tutorials but those didn't yield much.

My issue is the methods are getting called out of order. When MyActivity's XML file gets loaded, it also loads the fragment and calls its onCreate() method. This is done before I called the fragment's newInstance() method, so onCreate() doesn't have the parameters it needs to work.

What is the correct way to pass parameters to the fragment? Because clearly this isn't working. I've tried to simplify the code to exactly what is relevant.

Incase you want it, this is the specific error I'm getting:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class fragment
```

Line #18 points to the first line of the fragment tag.

**MyFragment.java**

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param";
        private int param

        public static MyFragment newInstance(int param) {
             MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
             Bundle args = new Bundle();
             args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param);
             fragment.setArguments(args);
             return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
             this.param = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
             // do stuff with param, but obviously param is not set
             // since constructor is called.
       }

       public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
            void onFragmentInteraction(String username);
       }

}
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_follower_list); // crashes at this line

        Fragment newFragment = ListOfUsersFragment.newInstance(TypeOfUserList.FOLLOWING, "TestingUsername");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.my_fragment, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String username) {
        // TODO (I'm just trying to get it to run first....
    }
}
```

**activity_my.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MyActivity">

    <!-- The following fragment's onCreate() method is called before newInstance() is called, causing issues. -->
    <fragment
        class ="xyz.mydomain.myproject.fragments.MyFragment"
        android:id="@+id/my_fragment"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: `newInstance` is YOUR factory method and it's never called if you put the fragment directly in the activity layout.

Answer (score 1):

Use getSupportFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager():

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_follower_list); // crashes at this line

    Fragment newFragment = ListOfUsersFragment.newInstance(TypeOfUserList.FOLLOWING, "TestingUsername");
    FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, newFragment);
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

Also in your Fragment class be sure it inherits from the Android framework support fragment:

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extents Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param";
    private int param

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int param) {
         MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param);
         fragment.setArguments(args);
         return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.param = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
         // do stuff with param, but obviously param is not set
         // since constructor is called.
   }

   public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(String username);
   }

}
```

Also use this layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MyActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Still throws the same error. There must be another error because that line of code doesn't even get run, it crashes two lines before, on the setContentView(stuff);.

Comment: And yeah, MyFragment extended fragment. Sorry, left that part out of the code accidentally.

Comment: ok, I just edited my answer, try using the layout without putting the fragment in it...make sure the ID of the root layout element is the same as the one you use in the fragment transaction

Answer (score 0):

create xml in res folder

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.androiddeveloper.demoapp.MyFragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello_blank_fragment" />

</FrameLayout>
```

java code here.

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public class MyFragment extents Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param";
    private int param

    public static MyFragment newInstance(int param) {
         MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
         Bundle args = new Bundle();
         args.putInt(ARG_PARAM1, param);
         fragment.setArguments(args);
         return fragment;
    }
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         this.param = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PARAM1);
         // do stuff with param, but obviously param is not set
         // since constructor is called.
   }

   public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        void onFragmentInteraction(String username);
   }

}
```

xml on of your activity

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.MyActivity">
</RelativeLayout>
```

call into YourActivity

```
public class MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_follower_list); // crashes at this line

        Fragment newFragment = ListOfUsersFragment.newInstance(TypeOfUserList.FOLLOWING, "TestingUsername");
        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace(R.id.my_fragment, newFragment);
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFragmentInteraction(String username) {
        // TODO (I'm just trying to get it to run first....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

might be the semicolon, you have not added semi colon.

instead of `private int param` should be `private int param;`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

instead of

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```